# Too many of these weird links showing up on GSC for my WP website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I have all of a sudden started to see too many issues showing up on my Google Search Console.

One of these is instant show up of 800 URLs showing "discovered - currently not indexed"

When I click on it, it shows these **weird URLs** as you may see which I don't know where they came up from .[the image shows some of these wierd links with "a1" or "a4" written at the end of my own URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKCfl.png)

Please help me out!

Comment: If those urls are not showing a 404 page and redirecting to any external website, Then you might have gotten infected by malware, clean up your website and install security plugins.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding

Showing the following in GSC:

(problem followed by number of URLS in the next line)

Page with redirect  
667
Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag  
626
Alternate page with proper canonical tag Website 
370
Soft 404 
4
Not found (404)
4
Discovered - currently not indexed 
858
Crawled - currently not indexed 
21
Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user Google systems 
3
Duplicate without user-selected canonical Website 
N/A
0


Total website pages (only 408 (indexed fine))
Also: Internal links at 27,000 somehow (unrelated maybe)